# Do academic historians regard the fact that the USSR was exporting food during the Holodomor as evidence that it was intentional?

Tags: historical-context, the-memory-keeper-of-kyiv, erin-litteken

Erin Littlekin claims in the afternote of *The Memory Keeper of Kyiv* that:

> Between 1932 and 1933, one in every eight Ukrainians died in this manmade famine. And it was absolutely manmade. During this time, the USSR exported tons of apples and tomato paste, barrels of pickles, honey, milk, and almost two million tons of grain in 1932 alone. Stores of crops, rotting sometimes as they awaited exportation, sat at railway stations and on the sides of roads under guard while the people starved within sight of them. Grain procurement quotas were kept unreasonably high, even though the spring seed grain had already been seized and the farmers of Ukraine had nothing left to give.
>
> Across the Soviet Union, food shortages resulting from the chaos of collectivization and dekulakization, and Stalin's refusal to lower grain quotas in the wake of these issues, lead to an estimated 8.7 million deaths... In August 1932, Stalin issued a statewide decree known as "The Law of Five Stalks of Grain," calling for ten years' imprisonment or death for anyone caught taking any state-owned property - which, to be clear, was *everything* - even a handful of grain, rotten potatoes from a field, or fish from a stream.

The author also cites laws like an internal passport system as evidence that Stalin was targeting Ukraine in particular (because Ukrainian nationalism was seen as a potential threat to Soviet ideology).

Do historians generally agree with the above analysis? Are such statistics and laws generally regarded as conclusive evidence that the famine was created intentionally?

Comment: There are two questions here: (a) in August 1932, when Stalin made these laws, was he intentionally setting up the Holodomor, and (b) in the winter of 1933, when Stalin learned that lots of people in Ukraine were dying, did he intentionally refuse to change his policies and save them?  There is some controversy about (a). There should be absolutely no controversy about (b).

Comment: A second question: did Stalin refuse to change his policy because he wanted to kill millions of people in Ukraine, or did he refuse to change his policy because he was unwilling to admit he had been wrong and didn't care about Ukrainians? I'd love to know the answer to that, but I think either answer shows that Stalin was fundamentally evil.

Comment: @PeterShor All very valid points. I don't know if it was incompetence at first and intransigence later, or if it was intentional all along. The author seems pretty convinced that it was deliberate all along; I'm curious as to whether the majority of historians agree with her perspective.

Comment: I've read that nobody can figure out whether it was intentional all along from the historical documents that we can access today. I don't know whether this was right or not, and I don't know whether any new evidence has appeared since then (but the place I read it was definitely not written by a Holodomor apologist, so I expect this is accurate).

Comment: I don’t know if the typo is the original author’s, but it should be ‘five stalks’ not ‘five stocks’.

Comment: "Do historians generally agree with the above analysis?" - This is a question for [se.history](https://history.stackexchange.com/). I'd say (not having resources to write a proper answer) that everything we know about Stalin suggests that it wasn't a specifically anti-Ukrainian policy. Rather, it was anti-peasant policy; peasants in Russia or Kazakhstan suffered the same fate. He just _disregarded_ them, believing there were higher priorities than these people. In addition, peasants were treated as unreliable class, despite the state declared as 'soviets of workers and peasants'.

Comment: @Zeus: my impression was that peasants in Russia did *not* suffer the same fate. Do you have some evidence that they did? (Of course, this doesn't mean it was a specific anti-Ukrainian policy.)

Comment: @Zeus: From [this website](https://www.nber.org/digest-202110/disproportionate-death-ukrainians-soviet-great-famine) "In 1926, Russians comprised 53 percent of the Soviet population, while Ukrainians, the largest ethnic minority, made up 21 percent. Yet between 30 and 45 percent of the 10.8 million victims of the Soviet Great Famine were ethnic Ukrainians." And that's an extremely low estimate for the number of Ukrainians who died. Most statistics I've seen say the number is between 5 and 7 million.

Comment: @Peter, as I said, if you want to discuss it properly, it's better to move the question to History. Yes, proportionally Ukrainians did suffer more (or in greater numbers), but more likely because the best and the most fertile agricultural land was there, hence greater share of peasants (who also were generally better off, making them 'class enemies'). Ukraine was also conveniently located on the west, closer to the export markets, and denser in population (compared to Russia), which made it a perfect target for concentrated expropriation efforts.

Comment: ...Nevertheless, we can't completely discount Stalin's (and generally Bolshevik's) disdain for the country that was [given off to the Germans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Brest-Litovsk) by them and thus was considered 'unreliable', just like everyone who was POW or under the German occupation during WWII was later considered a collaborator by default. Today we call it 'victim blaming'...